# What replaces the software center?

Tags: package-management, software-center

I get that the software center is going away, but what replaces it? I just installed ubuntu 15.10, mate, and its not here. Is there an alternative hiding some place? I installed synaptic for package management. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Evidently, for whatever reason, it wasn't installed, should I install gnome-software instead? or will the software center update itself to become gnome-software (auto-magically)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Software Center is installed in Ubuntu 15.10 by default.

If it is not installed in your system for some reason, install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

In 16.04 it will be replaced by Gnome Software. The package is called `gnome-software`, but Ubuntu Software Center is still available there as well.

Comment: I knew I should have included that last line :-P

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Mate 15.10 has a software center.

From the [press-kit](https://ubuntu-mate.org/ubuntu-mate-1510-presskit/):

> **Added Ubuntu MATE Welcome, a new utility unique to Ubuntu MATE.**
>
> - Welcome helps orientate users with their new operating system.
> - Welcome guides users through post-install configuration such as installing
>   drivers and adding language support.
> - Welcome provides a one-click installation from a highly curated list of best-in-class software to  "get stuff done".
> - The installation options include  ...
>
>   Steam, Google
>   Chrome, Dropbox, Spotify, Syncthing, Telegram, uGet, Minecraft, Gimp
>   (with CMYK support), InSync, SpiderOakONE, Skype, Google Music
>   Manager, VeraCrypt, Ubuntu SDK, Codecs, libdvdcss2, VirtualBox 5.0,
>   AppGrid, Ubuntu Software Centre and many others.

[image]

---

```
 sudo apt-get install software-center
```

will install the "old" software center if you want that. No need for synaptic but if you like that feel free. Choices. We are spoiled with them :-)

Answer (score -1):

Command line really, apt-get is strong it lets you do pretty much everything you need to related to handling your packages, once you get a hang of it, you won't need to use any GUI manager.